# One transaction with multiple dbcontexts

Tags: c#, .net, dbcontext, transactionscope

I am using transactions in my unit tests to roll back changes. The unit test uses a dbcontext, and the service i'm testing uses his own. Both of them are wrapped in one transaction, and one dbcontext is in the block of the other. The thing is, when the inner dbcontext saves his changes, it's not visible to the outer dbcontext (and i don't think it's  because the other dbcontext might already have the object loaded). Here is the example:

```
[TestMethod]
public void EditDepartmentTest()
{
    using (TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope())
    {
        using (MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext())
        {
            //Arrange
            int departmentId = (from d in db.Departments
                                   where d.Name == "Dep1"
                                   select d.Id).Single();
            string newName = "newName",
                   newCode = "newCode";

            //Act
            IDepartmentService service = new DepartmentService();
            service.EditDepartment(departmentId, newName, newCode);

            //Assert
            Department department = db.Departments.Find(departmentId);
            Assert.AreEqual(newName, department.Name,"Unexpected department name!");
            //Exception is thrown because department.Name is "Dep1" instead of "newName"
            Assert.AreEqual(newCode, department.Code, "Unexpected department code!");
        }
    }
}
```

The service:

```
public class DepartmentService : IDepartmentService
{
    public void EditDepartment(int DepartmentId, string Name, string Code)
    {
        using (MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext ())
        {
            Department department = db.Departments.Find(DepartmentId);

            department.Name = Name;
            department.Code = Code;

            db.SaveChanges();

        }
    }
}
```

However, if I close the outer dbcontext before calling the service and open a new dbcontext for the assert, everything works fine:

```
[TestMethod]
public void EditDepartmentTest()
{
    using (TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope())
    {
        int departmentId=0;
        string newName = "newName",
               newCode = "newCode";

        using (MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext())
        {
            //Arrange
            departmentId = (from d in db.Departments
                                   where d.Name == "Dep1"
                                   select d.Id).Single();
        }

        //Act
        IDepartmentService service = new DepartmentService();
        service.EditDepartment(departmentId, newName, newCode);

        using (MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext())
        {
            //Assert
            Department department = db.Departments.Find(departmentId);
            Assert.AreEqual(newName, department.Name,"Unexpected department name!");
            Assert.AreEqual(newCode, department.Code, "Unexpected department code!");
        }
    }
}
```

So basically i have a solution for this problem (thought of it during the writing of this question) but i still wonder why it isn't possible accessing uncommitted data in the transaction when the dbcontexts are nested.
Could it be becuase using(dbcontext) is like a transaction itself? If so, i still don't understand the issue since i'm calling .SaveChanges() on the inner dbcontext.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In the first scenario, you are nesting `DbContexts`. A connection to the database is opened for each on of them. When you call your service method within the `using` block, a new connection is opened within the `TransactionScope` while there is another one already open. This causes your transaction to be promoted to a [**distributed transaction**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254973.aspx), and partially committed data (the result of the `DbContext.SaveChanges` call in the service) not being available from your outer connection. Also note that distributed transactions are far slower and thus, this has the side effect of degrading performance.

In the second scenario, while you open and close three connections, only one connection is open at the same time within your transaction. Since these connections share the **same connection string**, the transaction won't be automatically promoted to a distributed connection and thus, each subsequent connection within the transaction has access to the changes performed by the previous connection.

You may try adding the `Enlist=false` parameter to your connection string. This would disable automatic enlisting in a distributed transaction, causing an exception to be raised in your first scenario. The second scenario would keep working flawlessly if you are using SQL Server 2008 and beyond, since the transaction won't get promoted. ([Prior versions of SQL Server will still promote the transaction in this scenario.](http://jeffmlakar.wordpress.com/2011/12/07/differences-in-escalation-to-distributed-transaction-coordinator-starting-in-sql-server-2008/))

You may also find helpful [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14584425/3042204) to a quite similar question.

Comment: Even with the same connection string you can have distributed transactions. They will be more lightweight than cross-server connections but they are still distributed. This effect is non-deterministic and therefore highly dangerous. During testing you are usually lucky. The OP was lucky. So while this answer is accepted and highly voted it is still incorrect in this particular regard.

Comment: @usr could you provide a link I can look into in order to improve the answer? Feel free to edit it yourself

Comment: This issue is hard to find but there are "official" Microsoft blogs about it and I have demonstrated it. I have no link at hand.

Comment: If we were to take the second scenario and get two different DB contexts inside the TransactionScope block (different connections strings), where would this leave us in terms of changes being accessible to the second DB context?

Answer (score 3):

Update: It seems this answer was unclear. It am *not* suggesting to keep DbContexts alive for as long as possible. Rather, use the Unit of Work pattern/idea. One context per UOW. Normally, this means one context per HTTP request, per GUI interaction or per test method. But it can be done differently if needed.

---

Using fresh contexts too frequently is an anti-pattern. Create one context and pass it around. It is very easy to do the passing around using a dependency injection framework.

Why not new contexts all the time? Because you want to be able to share entity object instances and pass them around. Other code can then modify them and at the end you call `SaveChanges` to persist everything atomically. This leads to very nice code.

> However, if I close the outer dbcontext before calling the service and open a new dbcontext for the assert, everything works fine

No, this was a coincidence because the 2nd context reused the connection of the 1st from the connection pool. This is not guaranteed and will break under load.

The *only* way to avoid distributed transactions is to use one connection which has been kept open.

You can have multiple contexts sharing the same connection, though. Instantiate with a manually created connection to do that.

Comment: I'm quite sure i read the exact opposite all over the internet and on msdn too

Comment: @sam what specifically are you referring to? Probably the first paragraph because the rest are indisputable facts. A context is supposed to live for as long as your unit of work goes. That's usually an HTTP request. This is not a controversial opinion. Shorter lifetimes are also possible but they prevent you from sharing entities across the app. An entity can only live in one context.

Comment: Seriously this is the first time i read about making dbcontext as long-lived as possible. One per request on web technologies, and much shorter life on client apps is what i always get. It may depend on the definition we have of long/short lived.

Comment: @sam I'm not claiming anything like that. As long as the unit of work is: `That's usually an HTTP request ... Shorter lifetimes are also possible`. There's no hard rule, there's only what works. I think we might actually have the same opinion here.

Comment: @usr could you please elaborate [here on related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50855464/dbcontext-savechanges-visibility-within-a-transactionscope)?

Answer (score 2):

This works:

public class Test1
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

```
public class Test2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class DC1 : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Test1> Test1 { get; set; }

    public DC1(SqlConnection conn)
        : base(conn, contextOwnsConnection: false)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("dc1");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Test1>().ToTable("Test1");
    }
}

public class DC2 : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Test2> Test2 { get; set; }

    public DC2(SqlConnection conn)
        : base(conn, contextOwnsConnection: false)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("dc2");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Test2>().ToTable("Test2");
    }
}
```

...

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EntityConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
{
    conn.Open();

    using (var tr = conn.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            using (var dc1 = new DC1(conn))
            {
                dc1.Database.UseTransaction(tr);
                var t = dc1.Test1.ToList();
                dc1.Test1.Add(new Test1
                {
                    Name = "77777",
                });
                dc1.SaveChanges();
            }
            //throw new Exception();
            using (var dc2 = new DC2(conn))
            {
                dc2.Database.UseTransaction(tr);
                var t = dc2.Test2.ToList();
                dc2.Test2.Add(new Test2
                {
                    Name = "777777",
                });
                dc2.SaveChanges();
            }
            tr.Commit();
        }
        catch
        {
            tr.Rollback();
            //throw;
        }
        App.Current.Shutdown();
    }
}
```

I guess it is better to fetch outside the transaction so no locking occurs, but I am not sure - need to investigate this myself

Update:
The above code works with code-first approach
The below code is for database-first

```
public MetadataWorkspace GetWorkspace(Assembly assembly)
{
    MetadataWorkspace result = null;
    //if (!mCache.TryGetValue(assembly, out result) || result == null)
    {
        result = new MetadataWorkspace(
            new string[] { "res://*/" },
            new Assembly[] { assembly });
        //mCache.TryAdd(assembly, result);
    }
    return result;
}
```

...

```
using(var conn = new SqlConnection("..."))
{
  conn.Open();
  using(var tr = conn.BeginTransaction())
  {
        using(var entityConnection1 = new EntityConnection(
            GetWorkspace(typeof(DbContext1).Assembly), conn))
      {
        using(var context1 = new ObjectContext(entityConnection1))
        {
          using(var dbc1 = new DbContext1(context1, false))
          {
            using(var entityConnection2 = new EntityConnection(
                GetWorkspace(typeof(DbContext2).Assembly), conn))
            {
                using(var context2 = new ObjectContext(entityConnection2))
                {
                  using(var dbc2 = new DbContext2(context2, false))
                  {
                    try
                    {
                        dbc1.UseTransaction(tr);
                        // fetch and modify data
                        dbc1.SaveChanges();

                        dbc2.UseTransaction(tr);
                        // fetch and modify data
                        dbc2.SaveChanges();

                        tr.Commit();
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        tr.Rollback();
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
          }
        }
      }
  }
}
```

It is useful when using many DbContexts in you app.
For example if you have thousands of tables - I just created so called "modules" with about hundred table per module. And each "module" has single context
sometimes though I need to do cross-module data modifications in a single transaction

Answer (score 1):

For me, using 'Enlist=false' in the config file removed the DST error, but also invalidated the transaction, DB changes were persistent even if scope scope.Complete() was not reached:

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope())  
using (var firstContext = new db1Context()) 
using (var secondContext = new db2Context())
{
// do smth with dbContexts
 scope.Complete();
}
```

I ended up using DbContextTransaction to solve this issue:

```
using (var firstContext = new db1Context())
using (var secondContext = new db2Context())
using (DbContextTransaction firstContextTransaction = db1Context.Database.BeginTransaction())
using (DbContextTransaction secondContextTransaction = db2Context.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
    try
    {
    // do smth with dbContexts                    
    firstContextTransaction.Commit();
    secondContextTransaction.Commit();
    }
    catch (System.Exception)
    {
    firstContextTransaction?.Rollback();
    secondContextTransaction?.Rollback();
    throw;
    }
    }
```