# How Can saveChanges twice inSide Two Diferrent DBcontext (Two different Entities framwork)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How Can saveChanges twice inSide Two Diferrent DBcontext (Two different Entities framwork)

```
try
{
    using (var context = new DBContext()) 
    { 
        using (var DBtran= context.Database.BeginTransaction()) 
        { 
            //something 

            using (var context2 = new DBContext2()) 
            { 
                using (var DBtran2= context2.Database.BeginTransaction()) 
                { 
                    //someThing
                    savechanges();
                    DBtran2.commit();
                    saveChanges();
                    DBtran.commit();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    DBtran.RollBack();
}
```

in my code I wan't to save data to Table into Dbcontext (Entity1) then 
I wan't to save the rest of data to table into Dbcontext 2 (Entity2)

Comment: what is savechanges thats non standard, context.SaveChanges() and context2.SaveChanges() are

Comment: alright ,context.savechanges()l ,and context2.savechanges()

Comment: I want to rollback the two transactions in Scope

Comment: are the connection strings between DBContext and DBContext2 the same

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21202982/one-transaction-with-multiple-dbcontexts

Comment: Not same it's different Entity