# How can I get an instance of DBContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In startup.cs file, I add custom application context to the services container:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var connection = @"...";                
        // Add Entity Framework services to the services container.
        services.AddEntityFramework()
            .AddSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]))
            .AddDbContext<MyContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));

...
```

In the `Configure` method of this same class, I can get an instance using this command:

```
app.ApplicationServices.GetService(typeof(MyContext)) as MyContext;
```

It works, because I have the `app` variable there.

In other business class, how can I get an instance of `MyContext`?

Comment: are you talking about `Dependency Injection`

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29083548/how-to-access-open-dbcontext-without-explicit-reference

Comment: Are you suggesting to pass context always it´s needed, right?