# Using Transactions and TransactionScopes with Entity Framework Core 2.1 and dbcontext

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, transactionscope

I'm trying to create dependent transactions in Entity Framework Core (v. 2.1).

The idea is to create "children" transactions inside a "father" transaction.

 If one of the childs fails, so will have the father, too.

I've tried with `TransactionScope`, but I've got the following error.

> Warning as error exception for warning
>   'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Transaction.AmbientTransactionWarning':
>   An ambient transaction has been detected. Entity Framework Core does
>   not support ambient transactions. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=800142 To suppress this
>   Exception use the DbContextOptionsBuilder.ConfigureWarnings API.
>   ConfigureWarnings can be used when overriding the
>   DbContext.OnConfiguring method or using AddDbContext on the
>   application service provider.

The followings are controller's methods, the dbcontext is created and initialized in the constructor of the controller

Here's my code:

```
public bool father()
    {
        using (var transaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))
        {
            try
            {
                //Do Stuff with the dbcontext 
                //(read, as "var x1 = _dbcontext.Database.Table1; etc...")...
                child();
                transaction.Complete();
                //Do Stuff...
            }
            catch
            {
                //Do Stuff...
                transaction.Dispose();
                //Do Stuff...
            }
        }
    }
}
public bool child()
    {
        using (var transaction2 = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))
        {
            try
            {
                //Do other stuff with the dbcontext
                //(read, as "var x2 = _dbcontext.Database.Table2; etc...")...
                transaction2.Complete();
                //Do Stuff...
            }
            catch
            {
                //Do Stuff...
                transaction2.Dispose();
                //Do Stuff...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: What is the  EFCore version you are using?

Comment: @user1672994 EFCore 2.1

Comment: EF Core *2.1* [isn't released yet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/), it's still in RC1. How did you add it?

Comment: @Deadpool suppressing a *runtime* warning that says transactions don't work is a very bad idea. Besides if the compiler *warns* you , you should listen and actually treat the warning as if it were an error

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I agree, but after I read the ef core 2.1 docs I found out that transactions are native in ef core 2.1 and googling the error I just had results about suppressing it. Personally, I would give a try... Alternatively, [the only way could be trying with declaring dbcontexts inside the transaction using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45919011/how-to-implement-ambient-transaction-in-entity-framework-core)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I've installed the release candidate… Deadpool Thanks, but actually I agree with Panagiotis about suppressing the error. I've tried, but it haven't worked. Also, I prefer to not declare db contexts inside each method. I would do it as a last try but I would prefer other solutions.

Comment: @Deadpool EF Core 2.1 isn't released yet. It's the version that actually adds support for TransactionScope. Telling someone to supress warnings that say transactions aren't working doesn't help.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You're right... I'm deleting the first comment in order to keep just the second one, which seems to be more useful

Comment: @SantaCloud .NET Core 2.1 goes RTM on Thursday, with the binaries already available for local installation. Perhaps you only need to wait a couple of days?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Hope so… But if in the meanwhile I hope also that someone found a solution or correct me if there is actually something logically wrong in my code (about that, in your opinion, do you think it's correct as it is?)

Comment: If you really want to, you can try the Early Access libraries which should (but doesn't have to) be same as those we will get on Thursday.
Details here: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/2.1.0-Early-Access-Downloads

Comment: @SantaCloud +1 for the username :)

Comment: @danpop Thanks man! :)